Check Status in Datasphere using Python
I want to check the status of a dataflow pipeline through a Python code, I want the code to return the status of the pipelines as completed or failed according to the run handle of the dataflow.

Is this feature available in Datasphere?
I am trying to figure out if this feature is available in Datasphere or not.
I have worked in Data Intelligence previously and this works. So, please let me know or where can i find the information?
